# Google Map is not Showing in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript

[Here is my Link](http://groupsnearme.com/) which shows the Map perfectly in Chrome, IE and Fire-fox but the map is not shown in Safari version 5.1.7. Can any one help me out to resolve this issue.

My JavaScript for google Map

```
<script>
    function writeAddressName(latLng) {

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ "location": latLng },
        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            }
            else
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br />";
        });
    }

    function geolocationSuccess(position) {
        var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        document.cookie = "latitude=" + position.coords.latitude;
        document.cookie = "longitude=" + position.coords.longitude;
        // Write the formatted address
        writeAddressName(userLatLng);


        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: userLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        };


        // Draw the map
        var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        // Place the marker
        new google.maps.Marker({
            map: mapObject,
            position: userLatLng
        });
        // Draw a circle around the user position to have an idea of the current localization accuracy
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: userLatLng,
            //radius: position.coords.accuracy,
            map: mapObject,
            //fillColor: '#0000FF',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            //strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0
        });
        mapObject.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
    }

    function geolocationError(positionError) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML + positionError.message + "<br />";
    }

    function geolocateUser() {
        // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var positionOptions = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
            };
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
        }
        else
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
    }

    window.onload = geolocateUser;
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map will only be drawn when geolocation is successfull, but at least for me it fails in Safari.

Instead   of creating the map in `geolocationSuccess` create the map initially with a default-center and when geolocation was successfull update the center of the map.

```js
function geolocateUser() {

  //draw the map:
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }, //default center at start
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
  };

  // Draw the map
  var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  // Place the marker
  mapObject.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('error'));

  function writeAddressName(latLng) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        "location": latLng
      },
      function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          document.getElementById("error")
            .innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
        } else
          document.getElementById("error")
          .innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your address";
      });
  }

  function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: mapObject,
      position: userLatLng
    });
    // Draw a circle around the user position to have an idea of the current localization accuracy
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: userLatLng,
      radius: position.coords.accuracy,
      map: mapObject,
      //fillColor: '#0000FF',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      //strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0
    });
    mapObject.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
    writeAddressName(userLatLng);

  }

  function geolocationError(positionError) {
      var e = {
        1: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
        2: 'POSITION_UNAVAILABLE',
        3: 'TIMEOUT'
      };
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'error:' + e[positionError.code];
    }
    // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var positionOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
    };
    navigator.geolocation['getCurrent'+'Position'](geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
  }

}

window.onload = geolocateUser;
```

```css
html,
      body,
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
      }
      #error {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 6px;
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="error"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Dr.Molle. I am new to implement Google map. so can you please explain what problem in my script

Comment: as i said, geolocation may fail, and when it fails your script doesn't create a map. It's more a logical mistake than a script-error.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you can you point out what changes i have to made in my script

Comment: Can you share any links which support google map in all browsers. It will be helpful for me to identify my mistake. Thank you

Comment: It's not a problem of google-maps or a specific browser(geolocation may fail in any browser or may be denied by the user). I've added an example above

Comment: Thank you for your response Dr.Molle. Ur suggested snippet is not working. Now in chrome also its not showing and i dont want a result as per your code. I want a result as in my link which shows the current location. Thank you

Comment: I guess there is something here on SO that blocks the geolocation, copy the code to your page and it will run.

Comment: Thank you Dr.Molle. I opened this fiddle (jsfiddle.net/t03Lvp6u) in safari it doesnot show the proper result

Comment: define "proper result"! Related to your question a proper result would be that you see a map. You don't see a map in safari?